# Neo4j export gml from java

Tags: export, neo4j, gml

i'm playing around with a lot of nodes and i really like neo4j! but i couldn't figure out how i export my embedded graph to a gml or similar standard graph file to visualise it in a third party app.

Do you have any example code for me?

thanks in advance!
jörn

Answer (score 0):

You should check out saveGML [method](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Methods) of Gremlin(a graph traversal language)

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of that via REST at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/gremlin-plugin.html#rest-api-load-a-sample-graph, in that case importing GML.